# Tooltip on heatmap and sparkline

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I created a heatmap and sparklines next to the heatmap.

[Here the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0i1heknvEqMWgL7w1TBL?p=preview)

There are errors in the code because the sparklines are not correct. The trend of the heatmap data is different from that of the sparklines. It seems that the data is read backwards.
Why?

Then, there are some data that are missing (colored in red). I wish in that case the sparklines were dashed or missing. How can I do that?

Assuming that the sparklines are right...

Now I would like that when the user hovers over a cell of theheatmap, a red dot is displayed on the corresponding sparkline.
On the other hand, when the user hovers over the sparkline, the corresponding cell in the heatmap is highlighted.

I hope it's clearer with some drawings:

[image]

I thought I could change the code at this point:

```
var cells = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .append('rect')
    //...
    .on('mouseover', tip.show) // <- HERE
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);
```

I should keep track of the rectangle on which the mouse is located and somehow pass this data to the piece of code that controls the sparkline.
But I don't really know how to do it and I have not found similar examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking three different questions here, which definitely qualifies your question as *too broad*. I'm answering the first two, regarding the sparklines, because they are related. I advise you posting the `mouseover` issue as a *new* post.

Back to the question:

The issue of the sparklines appearing to be inverted is easy to fix, just reverse the range of the `y` scale:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, maxYvalue]).range([itemSize-2, 2]);
```

The issue with missing values is a bit more complicated. First, you are using...

```
const sparkData = groupedData[key].map(function(datum) {
    return Number(datum['m2']);
})
```

... which turns all the missing data (empty strings) into `0`. That way, you simply cannot tell a real zero from a missing datum.

However, assuming that you indeed don't want to show `0` (which in your code is the same of a missing datum), you can use `defined` in the line generator:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .defined(function(d){
        return d
    })
```

Or more explicitly:

```
var line = d3.line()
    .defined(function(d){
        return d !== 0
    });
```

Finally, the last value in the third sparkline, which is not missing, will not show up because you cannot create a line with just one value... for showing that value you'll have to write a customised approach.

Here is the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JU11yj6p3VNtCBs5pjUF?p=preview